# How to escape backslash characters in PathBuf variables when writing to a JSON file?

Tags: json, rust

I'm very new to Rust - and this code is part of an artificial, learning project. Keep that in mind ;)

I have a collection of tuples: `&[(i32, String, String, PathBuf)]` that are passed into a function designed to write the data to a JSON file.

**The problem**: when I convert the `PathBuf` to a `&str` - the path written to file has unescaped backslash characters, so the JSON is invalid.

Here's the code:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub fn write_review_queue(ordered_review_queue: &[(i32, String, String, PathBuf)]) -> io::Result<()> {
    let output_file = "C:\\Dev\\Temp\\ReviewQueue\\review_queue.json";
    let mut buffer = try!(File::create(output_file));
    try!(buffer.write("{".to_string().as_bytes()));

    let mut is_first_item = true;
    for review_item in ordered_review_queue {
        if !is_first_item {
            try!(buffer.write(",".to_string().as_bytes()));
        }
        is_first_item = false;

        let json_string = "\"ReviewItem\": ".to_string() +
                          "{\"Index\": " + &review_item.0.to_string() + 
                          ", \"ReviewItemName\": \"" + &review_item.1 +
                          "\", \"ReviewItemPath\": \"" + &review_item.2 +
                          "\", \"MetadataPath\": \"" +  review_item.3.to_str().unwrap() +
                          "\"}";

        try!(buffer.write(json_string.as_bytes()));
    }


    try!(buffer.write("}".to_string().as_bytes()));
    Ok(())
}
```

And an example of the output:

```
{
    "ReviewItem": {
        "Index": 1,
        "ReviewItemName": "Crying Cat",
        "ReviewItemPath": "C:/Temp",
        "MetadataPath": "C:\Dev\Temp\ReviewQueue\Metadata\cryingcat.json"
    },
    "ReviewItem": {
        "Index": 2,
        "ReviewItemName": "Rusty Rat",
        "ReviewItemPath": "C:/Temp",
        "MetadataPath": "C:\Dev\Temp\ReviewQueue\Metadata\rustyrat.json"
    }
}
```

The code that produces the `PathBuf`s for the `MetadataPath`s is like this:

```
let metadata_files = metadata_read::read_filenames_from_dir("C:\\Dev\\Temp\\ReviewQueue\\Metadata");
    if !metadata_files.is_ok() {
        println!("reading metadata filenames failed");
        return;
    }

    let mut metadata_counts = Vec::new();
    for file in metadata_files.unwrap() {
        let metadata_field_count = metadata_read::count_nonempty_metadata_fields(&file, &keys);
        metadata_counts.push(metadata_field_count.unwrap());
    }
```

And the `count_nonempty_metadata_fields` function:

```
pub fn count_nonempty_metadata_fields(file_path: &PathBuf, metadata_keys: &[String]) -> Result<(i32, String, String, PathBuf), io::Error>
{
    // a bunch of code here...

    let path = file_path.to_path_buf();
    Ok((key_count, review_item_name, review_item_path, path))
}
```

If I change the original directory path string to:

```
let metadata_files = metadata_read::read_filenames_from_dir("C:/Dev/Temp/ReviewQueue/Metadata");
```

It does change the output, e.g.

```
{
    "ReviewItem": {
        "Index": 1,
        "ReviewItemName": "Crying Cat",
        "ReviewItemPath": "C:/Temp",
        "MetadataPath": "C:/Dev/Temp/ReviewQueue/Metadata\cryingcat.json"
    },
    "ReviewItem": {
        "Index": 2,
        "ReviewItemName": "Rusty Rat",
        "ReviewItemPath": "C:/Temp",
        "MetadataPath": "C:/Dev/Temp/ReviewQueue/Metadata\rustyrat.json"
    }
}
```

But it's still not right.

**Questions**

1. If I stick with this approach of building up a `String` in *hand-crafted* JSON format, how do I get the path content of the `PathBuf`s into a format with either forward-slashes or escaped backslashes? Am I missing something in the API?
2. Should I being using a `Json` object to build the data (which will probably be more reliable)? If so, what's the normal way to write the content of a `Json` object to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to *never* hand-generate any structured format, because eventually the output will become malformed. Additionally, your output has an object with the same two keys. While not *invalid*, it's likely not what you want.

In this case, you will quickly run into walls with trying to escape quotes and backslashes and maybe apostrophes and ampersands. You also have to keep track of the last item by hand. Let the library do the hard work.

There are two good JSON libraries for Rust: [rustc_serialize](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/index.html) and [serde](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde/index.html).

Step one is to create some actual types for your data. Tuples are great, but will you really remember that `foo.1` is the name... or was it `foo.2`?

Once you have that, you can simply output the slice:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;

#[derive(RustcEncodable)]
struct Item {
    index: i32,
    name: String,
    path: String,
    metadata_path: PathBuf,
}

fn write_review_queue(ordered_review_queue: &[Item]) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = try!(File::create("/tmp/output"));

    write!(buffer, "{}", json::as_json(&ordered_review_queue))
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Item { index: 0, name: "He\"llo".into(), path: "Good\\bye".into(), metadata_path: PathBuf::from(r#"C:\path\with'n\special"\chars"#)}];
    write_review_queue(&a).expect("Failed");
}
```

Unfortunately, this prints out the `PathBuf` in an ugly way:

```
[{"index":0,"name":"He\"llo","path":"Good\\bye","metadata_path":[67,58,92,112,97,116,104,92,119,105,116,104,39,110,92,115,112,101,99,105,97,108,34,92,99,104,97,114,115]}]
```

It's important to know that `PathBuf`s are **not** strings. Specifically, they are platform-dependent abstractions. On Unix-like systems the path is a collection of bytes close-to-but-not UTF-8, and on Windows it is close-to-but-not UCS-2.

You have to decide what lossy transformation is appropriate to convert it to true UTF-8 for your case. I'll use the one built-in to the standard library, [`to_string_lossy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_string_lossy). I also implement `ToJson` for the type to allow more customization:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::{self, ToJson, Json};

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

struct Item {
    index: i32,
    name: String,
    path: String,
    metadata_path: PathBuf,
}

impl ToJson for Item {
    fn to_json(&self) -> Json {
        let mut obj = BTreeMap::new();
        obj.insert("Index".to_string(), self.index.to_json());
        obj.insert("ReviewItemName".to_string(), self.name.to_json());
        obj.insert("ReviewItemPath".to_string(), self.path.to_json());
        obj.insert("MetadataPath".to_string(), self.metadata_path.to_string_lossy().to_json());
        obj.to_json()
    }
}

fn write_review_queue(ordered_review_queue: &[Item]) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = try!(File::create("/tmp/output"));

    write!(buffer, "{}", json::as_json(&ordered_review_queue.to_json()))
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Item { index: 0, name: "He\"llo".into(), path: "Good\\bye".into(), metadata_path: PathBuf::from(r#"C:\path\with'n\special"\chars"#)}];
    write_review_queue(&a).expect("Failed");
}
```

Note that this also allows you an opportunity to rename the keys of the object (although the names seem very redundant to me).

```
[{"Index":0,"MetadataPath":"C:\\path\\with'n\\special\"\\chars","ReviewItemName":"He\"llo","ReviewItemPath":"Good\\bye"}]
```

Comment: thanks for the depth of that answer, in addition to the `PathBuf` / `to_string_lossy()` info, there's a bunch of other improvements to work in. What did you mean by "Additionally, your output has an object with the same two keys. While not invalid, it's likely not what you want."? You're referring to double occurrence of `ReviewItem`? Also not worked with `JSON` much, but, if I interpret you correctly, I can output an "An ordered list of values" (array) rather than "A collection of name/value pairs" (terminology from http://json.org/)? In which case I don't need `ReviewItem`... thanks!

Comment: @GavinHope *double occurrence of `ReviewItem`* — yes, the second occurrence of the key will override the first occurrence. The code I've shown does output a JSON array of objects, which also means you can *probably* remove the `index` field (it's implicit from the order in the array).

Comment: Yes - with the ordered array I no longer need `Index`, thanks.